# Touch up inside anology for jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery

How can we achieve touch up inside event behavior in jquery mobile.

I want it behave exactly like native ios button. We can tap and hold tapping and move finger inside button **event will only fire if I release inside the button. Cancel if I release outside**

Comment: you question is not clear,you should describe the problem........

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile enables several new touch event categories:

**tap:**
A tap event, triggered when the user taps on an element

**taphold:**
A tap-and-hold event, triggered when the user taps and holds on an element for
about a second swipe
A swipe event, triggered when the user swipes either vertically (20 or fewer pixels)
or horizontally (30 or more pixels)

**swipeleft:**
A left-directed swipe, triggered when the user swipes to the left 30 or more pixels

**swiperight:**
A right-directed swipe, triggered when the user swipes to the right 30 or more pixels
All these events can be bound to elements using the usual jQuery bind, live, or
delegate methods.

how to use these touch events.

```
<script>
$("ul").delegate("li", "swiperight", function() {
// The user has swiped to the right on a list view item. Show an edit menu.
$(this).find(".menu-edit").show();
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried those even. None of them doesn't behave as I want. I updated the problem anyway.